# Spring Boot webclient multiple post api calls: Too many open files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

My spring boot application processes scheduled batch jobs which involves thousands of post api calls to configured apis in one batch job. These calls are processed simultaneously in a thread pool.

Below is the method used for each api call. It does not have any shared resources with other api calls.

```java
private <T> String getResponseV2(String deviceConnection, String uri, T body, Consumer<HttpHeaders> headersConsumer) {
        SslContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                    .forClient()
                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            log.error("Error creating ssl context: {}",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            log.error("Error: ",e);
            return null;
        }

        SslContext finalSslContext = sslContext;
        TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(finalSslContext));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient).wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL).responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(deviceConnection)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build()
                .post().uri(uri)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .headers(headersConsumer)
                .body(Mono.just(body), body.getClass())
                .retrieve()
                /*.onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, res -> {
                    log.info("Webclient Response {}", res.bodyToMono(String.class));
                    return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("Failed to Fetch Data"));
                })*/
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    }
```

In every individual job, this function is called twice, once for getting auth token, another for the actual post api call.

My issue is I am not fully familiar with webclient and not sure if this the correct way of using webclient for my use case, or if this is leaking resources.

This is because after some test runs i get the below exceptions in my service:

```
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketDgram(..) failed: Too many open files
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.newSocketDgram0(Socket.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.newSocketDgram(LinuxSocket.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDatagramChannel.<init>(EpollDatagramChannel.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDatagramChannel.<init>(EpollDatagramChannel.java:75)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll.getChannel(DefaultLoopEpoll.java:55)
    at reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources.onChannel(LoopResources.java:214)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.onChannel(TcpResources.java:208)
    at reactor.netty.transport.NameResolverProvider.lambda$newNameResolverGroup$0(NameResolverProvider.java:415)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:310)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.register(AbstractBootstrap.java:227)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.<init>(DnsNameResolver.java:456)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.build(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:476)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newNameResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:114)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:92)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:77)
    at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:70)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

These are either accompanied with this

```
tack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:137)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:221)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:224)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:273)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:413)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:189)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:306)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:166)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:427)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$5(SimpleDequePool.java:310)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:565)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator.lambda$connectChannel$0(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:525)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4161)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4017)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3953)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3925)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drainLoop(SimpleDequePool.java:318)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drain(SimpleDequePool.java:261)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.doAcquire(SimpleDequePool.java:256)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:382)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onSubscribe(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:206)
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:578)
        at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$1(PooledConnectionProvider.java:120)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:266)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:76)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:269)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1702)
        at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.getResponseV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:197)
        at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.setConfigurationItemV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:119)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processApi(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:71)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processDeviceJob(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:44)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba9a8368.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703)
        at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.getResponseV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:197)
        at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.setConfigurationItemV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:119)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processApi(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:71)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processDeviceJob(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:44)
        at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba9a8368.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketStream(..) failed: Too many open files
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.newSocketStream0(Socket.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.newSocketStream(LinuxSocket.java:319)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.LinuxSocket.newSocketStream(LinuxSocket.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel.<init>(EpollSocketChannel.java:45)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll.getChannel(DefaultLoopEpoll.java:49)
    at reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources.onChannel(LoopResources.java:214)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.onChannel(TcpResources.java:208)
    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig.lambda$connectionFactory$0(TransportConfig.java:265)
    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.doInitAndRegister(TransportConnector.java:171)
    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.connect(TransportConnector.java:102)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator.lambda$connectChannel$0(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:524)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4017)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3953)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3925)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drainLoop(SimpleDequePool.java:318)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.drain(SimpleDequePool.java:261)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.doAcquire(SimpleDequePool.java:256)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.request(AbstractPool.java:382)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onSubscribe(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:206)
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool$QueueBorrowerMono.subscribe(SimpleDequePool.java:578)
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$1(PooledConnectionProvider.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:266)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:269)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1702)
    at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.getResponseV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:197)
    at .service.AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.setConfigurationItemV2(AirLinkOSDeviceServiceWebClientImpl.java:119)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processApi(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:71)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processDeviceJob(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:44)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba9a8368.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: newSocketStream(..) failed: Too many open files
```

or this

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.save(Unknown Source)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processApi(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:99)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.processDeviceJob(DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService.java:44)
    at .service.DeviceScheduledJobAsyncService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba9a8368.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
2023-12-13 08:13:51,459  WARN [b7403dc2-fc7c-4249-9b61-dbb98cb96e8d] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [FunctionThread-9] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2023-12-13 08:13:51,459  ERROR [b7403dc2-fc7c-4249-9b61-dbb98cb96e8d] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [FunctionThread-9] The connection attempt failed.
```

Either way the culprit seems to be too many open files.

I am a little lost since i am not able to exactly pin point what the issue is and what i could do to resolve it.

I am running my application in a docker container.

Is increasing the file descriptor limit the only fix for it?

Comment: I suspect creating a new TcpClient and a new ReactorClientHttpConnector, on every single request, and never closing either of them, is leading to the resource leak you're showing.  Spring Boot can autoconfigure a `WebClient.Builder` for you; can you get one of those dependency-injected, and delete almost everything above the `.post()` line?

Comment: @DavidMaze i will try doing that. Thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, that worked. It significantly increased the throughput as well, so much so I have a question to ask about webclient. Now that i have a singleton webclient, if i am submitting 10 api jobs into 10 different threads, how does webclient handle/process the 10 tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is creating a lot of basic resources on every HTTP call.  Things like the SSL context, for example, will be pretty much fixed across the entire application.  If some of these resources include things like connection pools, then you're creating a new connection pool on every request; that would lead to the resource exhaustion you're seeing.

In a very general sense, you'll want to create objects like that `SslContext` or `HttpClient` only once in your application, and then pass them into objects as they need them.  One of the core features of Spring is a *dependency injection* system that provides a standard way to create these objects once and inject them into objects as they need them.

But more specifically, Spring Boot already contains logic to create most of these things on its own.  You shouldn't have to create any of these objects at all.  Ask Spring Boot to pass a `WebClient.Builder` to your object's constructor, and it will oblige.

```java
@Component
public class MyService {
  private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

  public MyService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
  }

 private <T> String getResponseV2(
    String deviceConnection,
    String uri,
    T body,
    Consumer<HttpHeaders> headersConsumer
  ) {
    // without creating any of the other objects
    return WebClient.builder()
      .clone()
      .baseUrl(deviceConnection)
      .build()
      .post().uri(uri)
      ...;
  }
}
```

The Spring Boot documentation has more information on [injecting and configuring a WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.rest-client.webclient).  If you do need custom TLS configuration, for example, there is a Spring-specific path where you can provide a [`WebClientSsl` object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.rest-client.webclient.ssl) without constructing this entire object stack from scratch.